# I'm not able to export to csv despite slaveOk 1

Tags: mongodb, csv, parsing, export-to-csv, mongoexport

```
mongoexport --host a.a.a.a --port 2346234 -slaveOk 1 -d meritnation -c user_rewards_points --csv --out badgesnew.csv -f userId, TotalPoints, Bronze.DEDICATED, Bronze.STUDIOUS, Bronze.FUN_LEARNER, Bronze.POPULAR, Bronze.ENLIGHTENED, Bronze.ENTHUSIAST, Bronze.WELL_CONNECTED, Bronze.AUTOBIOGRAPHER
```

I want to export the following to csv and I'm getting the following error:

> **Error parsing command line: too many positional options**

Comment: what is your mongodb version? Do you really wanted to read from slave?

Comment: version 2.6 and yes

Comment: The error message is telling you that you've got a syntax problem somewhere in the command line parameters; have you double-checked every single option to make sure that it has a space (or not) as required, that values are quoted where necessary etc?

Comment: removed spaces, and checked once again still didn't work - I'll go through each line and let you know once again after checking

Comment: Just to check whether it is a syntax or reading from slave problem, you can change to master host, port and remove slaveOk and try the command. I think this should not be a syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below command and check whether the secondary has a **slaveDelay** applied. Applying a slaveDelay hides the secondary from the discovery mechanisms that clients use to discover replica set members (the same behavior as setting hidden to true). Since Mongos does not see the secondary it can't use it for the query.

```
rs.conf()
```

Check the output of 'ismaster', which clients use for discovery and query routing

```
rs.isMaster()
```

If you don't want to read from slave, you can remove the slave ok and try your query.

[More information about slaveDelay](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/lMoeTZ49eJk)

See the last comment from Bernie

Comment: What is your output for rs.isMaster()? Are you getting the secondary on the result set? If you are not getting the secondary on isMaster() result set,  can you run this rs.slaveOk() and try the isMaster again?